# SWF html Strech swf to screen size?

Tags: flash

how can i strech the swf to the screen size of the current computer?

heres my code

```
<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"

WIDTH="850"

HEIGHT="610"

CODEBASE="http://active.macromedia.com/flash5/cabs/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0">

<PARAM NAME="MOVIE" VALUE="2bigpinkballs2.swf">

<PARAM NAME="PLAY" VALUE="true">

<PARAM NAME="LOOP" VALUE="true">

<PARAM NAME="QUALITY" VALUE="high">

<PARAM NAME="SCALE" value="noborder">

<EMBED SRC="aa.swf"

WIDTH="850"

HEIGHT="610"

PLAY="true" 

LOOP="true"

QUALITY="high" 

scale="noborder"

PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"> 

</EMBED>

</OBJECT>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s actually pretty simple. Here’s some of the CSS I used:

```
/* hide from ie5 mac \*/
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#flashcontent {
  height: 100%;
}
/* end hide */
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Setting the html tag to 100% height and then placing the Flash movie inside a div that is also set to 100% height does the trick.